# split 関数での分割時に区切り文字を残したい

Tags: python, python3

`宮の森二条13丁目` という文字に対して `宮の森二条` , `１３丁目` に区切るとき、以下のコードでは期待とは異なる結果となってしまいます。

```
s = '宮の森二条１３丁目'
s.split('条')
→['宮の森二', '１３丁目']
```

これを `['宮の森二条', '１３丁目']` としたいのですが、方法がわかりません。ご教授ください。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

以下は正規表現の後読み(look behind)を使う方法です。

```py
import re

s = '宮の森二条１３丁目'
re.split(r'(?<=条)', s)

#=>
['宮の森二条', '１３丁目']
```

Comment: ありがとうございます！

Answer (score 0):

正規表現のグルーピングを使う方法です。

```
>>> import re
>>> s = '宮の森二条１３丁目'
>>> m = re.match('^(.*条)(.*)$', s)
>>> l = list(m.group(1,2))
>>> print(l)
['宮の森二条', '１３丁目']
```

Comment: これは「ただしくない回答」ではないのでマイナス票を入れた投票者は見識が無い。